Kubuntu 22.04 Problem with Kernel 6.8.0. After update from Kernel 6.5.0-45 to 6.8.0 system freezes
Last week, I updated my Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. The update contained a new Kernel 6.8.0. After restart the system froze while login. Mouse and keyboard didn't react. Only a hard shutdown with some seconds on the on/off button was possible.
Some later attempts were not successful too. Booting in safe mode worked, but only in poor graphics. Next I tried booting the old Kernel 6.5.0-45 and everything worked fine.
As a first workaround I deinstalled the new Kernel and now my system works stable.
Afterwards I tried to start Kubuntu 24.04 LTS from USB-stick. Same effect, desktop freezes shortly after start, same with Linux Mint 22.
My system is Lenovo ThinkPad T510, Intel Core i5 with builtin graphics MesaIntel HD
Now I am remainded to upgrade to 24.04 LTS, but I dont know if I could roll back to my 22.04 6.5.0-45 if I had the same Problem after the upgrade. Will grub give me the choice to boot the old 22.04 after upgrade to 24.04?

The answer is no, once you upgrade you can not go back unless you install 22.04 as a new operating system.
I suggest you wait to upgrade until version 24.04.01 is out and if you want to try it first take an image of your disk, you can use either Clonezilla or dd first. That is the only way you can get back to version 22.04 if you don't want to go through a new installation.
There will be kernel upgrades, and you can check them the same way you did, maybe at a later date there will be a kernel that doesn't freeze your computer.

The first point release of Ubuntu 24.04, Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, has been officially released. Now you can upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. I recommend to make your system stable and disable all PPAs from your software sources before upgrading. If a non-essential package that you don't need is interfering with the upgrade you can uninstall it. The upgrade is not reversible, so you cannot roll Ubuntu 24.04 back to Ubuntu 22.04 after upgrading Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.
